# OnPressed open textformfield on differrnt page flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

There's a button on my home page which when clicked should redirect me to another page and click on  textformfield on that page,I dont know how to do that

Comment: can you please elaborate on your problem statement? I and also others are unable to understand what you are trying to ask. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

just use autofocus: true on another page

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return NextPage();
                },
              ));
            },
            child: Text("Click")),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NextPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TextField(
        autofocus: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this works thanks but i want to focus textfield only when i click a button on another screen,if i navigate to the text field from another button it shouldnt autofoucs then

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple ways to do this depending on your use case

1- if you want to focus on the text form field every time you enter the page you change autofocus property in the textField to true,

```
    TextField(
      autofocus:true,
    )
```

2- if you want to trigger focus on a textfield by manually you can use FocusNode object, this focus node will be attached to your text field.

First you need to initialize the object.

```
FocusNode myFocusNode;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    myFocusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the focus node when the Form is disposed.
    myFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

then Attach the focus node object to your text field

```
TextField(
      focusNode: myFocusNode,
);
```

Now you can use this focus node in a function to focus on this text

```
// focus on textfield (same as text field pressed)
myFocusNode.requestFocus() 


// unfocus  on textfield (same as pressing done on textfield or pressing the back button)
myFocusNode.unfocus()
```

you can pass a flag to the new page you are going to, which will trigger the focus function

Answer (score 0):

Use  onTap in TextFormField using that you can redirect your text form feild to another screen

```
 TextFormField(
              controller: _descriptionController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Description'),
              onTap: (){    Get.to(() => DescriptionScreen());},
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter description';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
```